# Have a Question about Mongodb Aggregate if nested

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, lookup

I'm making a function using aggregate . I am working on tying three DBs using lookup. When the function below is composed, is there a way to bind the data of A and the data of C?

```
A.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "B",
        let: { aid: "$aid" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$aid"] } } },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "C",
              let: { bid: "$bid" },
              pipeline: [
                {
                  $match: {
                    $expr: {
                      $eq: ["$$bid, "$aid"],
                    },
                  },
                },
              ],
              as: "list",
            },
          },
        ...
  ])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what do you mean by "tying" and "bind"? From your example, you should be able to lookup data in C from A already

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to find a value in C's pipeline that matches A's field.

Comment: Is there any difference between looking up C from A and looking up A from C? You may want to give us some sample data and expected output to show us what you want to achieve. [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/) would be one of the useful tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been learning a bit more about this and I've found the results I'm looking for by doing the following:

```
A.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "B",
        let: { bid: "$bid", aid: "$aid" },
        pipeline: [
          { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$bid"] } } },
          {
            $lookup: {
              from: "C",
              localField: "_id",
              foreignField: "cid",
              as: "list",
            },
          },
          {
            $unwind: "$list",
          },
          // One More Match
          {
            $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$$aid", "$list.aid"] } },
          },
          {
            $addFields: {
              list: "$list.clist",
            },
          },
        ],
        as: "blist",
      },
    },
  ])
```